# How do i stop the horizontal bounce in the AppPageTabBarController

Tags: cosmicmind

How do i stop the horizontal bounce in the AppPageTabBarController, when swiping the tabs, the first and last one you can drag and bounce.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `PageTabBarController.isBounceEnabled` flag you can set. It stops all swiping though. I am currently rewriting the `PageTabBarController` and have added this feature into the list of updates.